# Failing to access a java array returned from a java method called from Octave

Tags: java, type-conversion, octave, weka

I am tryring to run a weka classifier from Octave, annd trying to access the confusion matrix. first I create a classifier and a evaluation object from Octave

```
 classifier = javaObject('weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes');

 evl=javaObject('weka.classifiers.Evaluation',Testor);   % here testor
 is a previously created java object

 v = javaArray ("java.lang.String", 4);
 v(1)=javaObject('java.lang.String','-t');
 v(2)=javaObject('java.lang.String','train.arff');
 v(3)=javaObject('java.lang.String','-T');
 v(4)=javaObject('java.lang.String','test.arff');


 pred = evl.evaluateModel(classifier,v);%test
```

Upto this point code works fine. I checked the outputs of pred, which are fine. Problem is when I try to call confusionMatrix from this evl object.

```
cm=javaMethod("confusionMatrix",evl)
```

this returned object cm seems to be a Java object: double[][] 
I checked the size, which is 2x2 occupying 0 bytes(!), but i find no way to convert it to an octave matrix and read the values.

Please help me and let me know if this question needs anything to improve

Answer (score 0):

Simply declare an array of primitive type by:

**ar2D = javaArray ("java.lang.String", 2, 2);** %2D array of String

[This image show you how to do that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HvHw.png)

You can declare an object by this method:

**obj = javaObject ("java.util.Random");**

**a = obj.nextInt();**

If you want to create an object of user defined class then first of all create jar containing this class and add the jar in your java static class path. Or you can add your current class path as JVM dynamic class path by this approach and then you can create the object of your classes.

Checking Current directory: **curDir = pwd ;**

Adding your dynamic class path: **javaaddpath ([curDir, "/JAR_NAME.jar"]);**

Check that you have successfully added your class path:

**p = javaclasspath;**

**disp(p);**

Now create your object as described before.

[Creating java object in octave](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NcKq.png)

Comment: this is not relevant, I have already got my prediction results in the pred vector which is a string, means the returned objects are working fine. Somehow there is a problem with the confusion matrix function or the returned array of doubles.

Answer (score 0):

For this specific problem, just type this line:

```
cm = evl.confusionMatrix();
```

First of all make sure that "**evl**" object is really created and it's a java object. There have a built-in method in Octave named  "**isjava(JAVA_OBJECT)**" which get an object and return true if it's a java object or return false.

You can simply check it by this method.

Your code should look like this:

```
if( isjava(evl))

    cm = evl.confusionMatrix();

    %Other logical staff here
end
```

Hope this will work fine.

Comment: I have checked it and it is a javaobejct, but how this checking can help? In the previous line i get pred - which is a large string and that works fine. I guess its a problem with the conversion of a Java Array object to octave. it successfully returns are correct sized arraya, however, the interpretation is 0 bytes. I saw some patches: http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/?44882#attached but I am not sure if my problem is exactly this one. Looking for other solutions, otherwise might apply the patch.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution myself. Weka returns a fastvector data structure. I had to go through the documentation of fast vectors to read that.